# Ориентация экрана и AsynTask Android

Tags: android, парсер, android-asynctask, синтаксический-анализ

Есть проблема. 
AsynTask грузит данные по JSON, так вот, если **во время** загрузки повернуть экран, то приложение выпадает. Как решить эту задачу? Помогите. Вот код всего активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ListView list;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> keyList;
// Adapter adapter;
String             baseURL="http://echo.jsontest.com/key1/value1/key2/value2/key3/value3/key4/value4";
private static final String KEY4 = "key4";
private static final String KEY3 = "key3";
private static final String KEY2 = "key2";
private static final String KEY1 = "key1";
ListAsynTask lat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    new ListAsynTask().execute(baseURL);
}

public class ListAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Подождите...идет загрузка");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
                keyList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                HashMap<String, String> neww = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Iterator itr = json.keys();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    String key = itr.next().toString();

                    neww.put(key, (String) json.get(key));
                    keyList.add(neww);
                }

            }
            return true;
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, keyList,
                R.layout.items,new String[]{KEY4, KEY3,KEY2,KEY1 }, new int[]{R.id.key4,R.id.key3,R.id.key2,R.id.key1});

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: При повороте Activity уничтожается. Поэтому логично, что в onPostExecute при доступа к контексту/GUI будет Exception.

Comment: вместо onPost нужно использовать onProgressUpdate? не пойму как

Comment: @Alerx это не исправит проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в обьявление вашего Activity в манифесте такое:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Получится в итоге что-то в роде

```
<activity          
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Или ссылку на активити сохранять в AsyncTask'е и к ней обращаться.
[Вот тут написано как](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/154-urok-91-asynctask-povorot-ekrana).