# Как узнавать об изменении ориентации экрана android

Tags: java, android

Нужно узнавать именно об изменении и если она была изменена выполнять метод. Пытался гуглить, но нашел лишь вариант для узнавания текущей ориентации, что не подходит, кстати это мне помогло [Ориентация экрана и AsynTask Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/387301/%d0%9e%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8-asyntask-android) и я тоже использую `AsyncTask`, но теперь у меня не переключается на `landscape` версию xml активности.

Comment: [android:configChanges](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) в документации указано, какой метод жизненного цикла активности будет вызываться, если установить этот флаг)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

- Использовать [OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html), которая имеет метод [onOrientationChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html#onOrientationChanged(int)).
- Используйте изменение конфига:

В вашем манифесте:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloAndroid"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation">
```

В вашей активити переопределите onConfigurationChanged:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    int newOrientation = newConfig.orientation; 
}
```

- Как добавил Circassian есть еще такой вариант:

Текущая конфигурация, используемая для определения того, какие ресурсы получить, доступна из объекта `Configuration`:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

Вы можете проверить ориентацию, посмотрев на ее значение:

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    // Горизонтальная
} else {
    // Портретная
}
```

Comment: Есть еще [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795833/check-orientation-on-android-phone/2799001#2799001) вариант